# Not Able to Set "divId.Visible = false" in Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried following code. But it shows:

> The name 'commonMessage' does not exist in the current context

Index.cshtml

```
<div id="commonMessage" runat="server" style="color: red"></div>
```

Controller:

```
commonMessage.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mvc does not have the same "code behind" consept as asp.net webforms. You can not reach your frontend-code in that way.

You have to show us all the code in the controller so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

That code would work if you were using WebForms Asp.Net and not using MVC.

What you need to do is have a variable in the controller ,to set the style Display=none or Display=block, eg

```
var DivIsVisible = false;
```

Then in the cshtml you would write, something like:

```
<div class="@(Model.DivIsVisible?"visible-item":"hidden-item")">Some links</div>
```

Another way:

```
@if(Model.DivIsVisible)
{
  <div>Some link</div>
}
```